# Cypher Nested Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Trying to build nested query in cypher sql to find the grosssale, sales by distinctcustomer and salesreach and not able to pass column 1 value as input to another column - any help would be appreciated.

Syntax here

```sql
MATCH (n:Commercial)
WITH (n) AS grosssales, count(n) AS distinctcustomer, 
  n.customer_id AS customer, ### grouping by customer_id ###
  grosssale / distinctcustomer AS salesreach
RETURN grossale, distinctcustomer, salesreach, customer_id
```

Tried WITH clause however no joy, would appreciate any help in correcting the cypher syntax.

Comment: What's the output you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
MATCH (n:Commercial) 
WITH count(n) AS grosssales 
MATCH (c:Commercial) 
WITH grosssales,count(c) AS distinctcustomer, c.customer_id AS customer, tofloat(grosssales/count(c)) AS salesreach 
RETURN imp AS grosssales, distinctcustomer, customer, salesreach
```

Comment: Does not work, as `imp` is not defined.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query by using the new [COUNT subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/subqueries/count/) (in neo4j 5.0+) to count the total number of `Commercial` nodes. Although `COUNT()` is an aggregating function, a COUNT subquery is not -- so it is not affected by the `customer` grouping key.

```
MATCH (c:Commercial) 
WITH COUNT{ (:Commercial) } AS grosssales, COUNT(c) AS distinctcustomer, c.customer_id AS customer
RETURN grosssales, distinctcustomer, customer, TOFLOAT(grosssales/distinctcustomer) AS salesreach
```